# Copying embeddings for gensim word2vec

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I wanted to see if I can simply set new weights for gensim's Word2Vec without training. I get the 20 News Group data set from scikit-learn (from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups) and trained an instance of Word2Vec on it:

```
model_w2v = models.Word2Vec(sg = 1, size=300)
model_w2v.build_vocab(all_tokens)
model_w2v.train(all_tokens, total_examples=model_w2v.corpus_count, epochs = 30)
```

Here all_tokens is the tokenized data set. 
Then I created a new instance of Word2Vec without training

```
model_w2v_new = models.Word2Vec(sg = 1, size=300)
model_w2v_new.build_vocab(all_tokens)
```

and set the embeddings of the new Word2Vec equal to the first one

```
model_w2v_new.wv.vectors = model_w2v.wv.vectors
```

Most of the functions work as expected, e.g.

```
model_w2v.wv.similarity( w1='religion', w2 = 'religions')
> 0.4796233
model_w2v_new.wv.similarity( w1='religion', w2 = 'religions')
> 0.4796233
```

and

```
model_w2v.wv.words_closer_than(w1='religion', w2 = 'judaism')
> ['religions']
model_w2v_new.wv.words_closer_than(w1='religion', w2 = 'judaism')
> ['religions']
```

and

```
entities_list = list(model_w2v.wv.vocab.keys()).remove('religion')

model_w2v.wv.most_similar_to_given(entity1='religion',entities_list = entities_list)
> 'religions'
model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar_to_given(entity1='religion',entities_list = entities_list)
> 'religions'
```

However, most_similar doesn't work:

```
model_w2v.wv.most_similar(positive=['religion'], topn=3)
[('religions', 0.4796232581138611),
 ('judaism', 0.4426296651363373),
 ('theists', 0.43141329288482666)]

model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar(positive=['religion'], topn=3)
>[('roderick', 0.22643062472343445),
> ('nci', 0.21744996309280396),
> ('soviet', 0.20012077689170837)]
```

What am I missing?

Disclaimer. I posted this question on [datascience.stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53601/copying-embeddings-for-gensim-word2vec) but got no response, hoping to have a better luck here.

Comment: Surprising problem. It may be a problem of the way the distance is calculated. Can you share the output of ``model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar_cosmul(positive=['religion'], topn=3)`` ? Maybe one of the model is calculating in cosine distance instead of euclidean by default

Comment: `model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar_cosmul(positive=['religion'], topn=3)` has the same effect and the same result as `model_w2v_new.wv.most_similar(positive=['religion'], topn=3)`. gojomo gave the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, your approach should work.

It's likely the specific problem you're encountering was caused by an extra probing step you took and is not shown in your code, because you had no reason to think it significant: some sort of `most_similar()`-like operation on `model_w2v_new` **after** its `build_vocab()` call but **before** the later, malfunctioning operations.

Traditionally, `most_similar()` calculations operate on a version of the vectors that has been normalized to unit-length. The 1st time these unit-normed vectors are needed, they're calculated – and then cached inside the model. So, if you then  replace the raw vectors with other values, but don't discard those cached values, you'll see results like you're reporting – essentially random, reflecting the randomly-initialized-but-never-trained starting vector values.

If this is what happened, just discarding the cached values should cause the next `most_similar()` to refresh them properly, and then you should get the results you expect:

```
model_w2v_new.wv.vectors_norm = None
```

Comment: yes, model_w2v_new.wv.vectors_norm = None did the trick, thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why `most_similar()` calculations operate on a version of the vectors that has been normalized to unit-length and cashed, but other functions, e.g. `most_similar_to_given` do not?

Comment: Using the cached unit-normed vectors is much faster, if they're available, especially for an operation like `most_similar()` which must calculate a value for **every** vector in the model – and thus also uses bulk array operations on the full vector array, rather than the one-at-a-time calcs relied upon by `most_similar_to_given()`. (`most_similar_to_given()` could, and perhaps should, use the same cached values, but wouldn't get as much of a speedup.)

Comment: Thank you. "'most_similar_to_given()' could, and perhaps should, use the same cached values,". It definitely can use it. In my case, I'm comparing a word to all other words in the corpus and it takes >0.6 sec for 'most_similar_to_given()' and ~2ms for 'most_similar()'

Comment: Note that just using cached values *wouldn't* close that full speed gap. The `most_similar()` op is also faster because it can do a bulk array operation on the full array, which typically uses a native optimized routine rather than a Python-loop. The only way to do that is to have all the relevant vectors in a contiguous memory array – and for large sets of "given" vectors, creating such an extra array copy would be another drag. So if you really are comparing against "all", or even "lots", you should use `most_similar()` directly, & filter the results – no other approach can be competitive.